# Would Earth without water look like Mars?

Tags: mars, water, earth

I was watching [this](https://www.geeksaresexy.net/2020/07/21/new-4k-footage-of-mars-surface-video/) slideshow of 4K images of the surface of Mars, and I noticed that the surface looked mostly smooth, with the most rugged features being crater impacts (*sort of* resembling an Earth desert). That got me thinking, would the Earth, if water never were on it, look like Mars does now?

I know that water is responsible for some major features on the surface of Earth, such as The Grand Canyon. I know that Earth's tectonic plates were responsible for another part of our features, i.e. Mount Everest (although the largest mountain in our solar system, (Olympus Mons) is on Mars). I know that Mars, although technically having tectonic plates, [has not seen a lot of tectonic activity 'recently'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tectonics_of_Mars).

With all of that in mind, would Mars be a good approximation of Earth without water?

**Edit:** Upon doing more research, water has been on Mars. My question therefore may be better asked: Would Mars be a good approximation of Earth with little to no water, or if water were to somehow disappear for an extended period of time?

Comment: It would have a lot more air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Quite possibly

Upon learning that Mars did have surface water at some point, you have updated your question to ask if Mars would be a good approximation for Earth if Earth had little to no water, or if the water had been missing for a period of time.  Conversely, try looking at areas of the Earth that have had little to no water, or where the water has been missing for a period of time: Southern Utah.

Southern Utah is often used for Earth-based simulations of Martian Terrain, as it is similar: Large rocks worn smooth by blowing sand, canyons formed by long-ago rivers, "[marbles](https://www.deseret.com/2004/6/17/19835177/southern-utah-marbles-may-offer-clues-to-mars#marjorie-chan-of-the-u-holds-a-collection-of-moqui-marbles-from-southern-utah-similar-iron-secretions-have-been-found-on-mars)" similar to the "blueberries" found on Mars. Several organizations use Southern Utah as a Mars simulator: The [Mars Desert Research Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Desert_Research_Station) and [University Rover Challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_Rover_Challenge) are both run by the Mars Society, and I believe NASA has conducted some experiments there as well.